# Manipulating buttons in different Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel, jbutton

I have a various panels with various buttons. Some buttons should call a method initiating a search through an array list, other buttons should call methods that send information to different JTextArea boxes.
After adding an event listener for each button, how do I create specific actions depending on the button clicked in my actionPerformed method? Below is my code for various gui properties, as you can see there are 3 different JPanels, the buttons of each needing to perform different functions. I just need to know how to determine which button was clicked so I can link it to the appropriate method (already written in another class). Does this require an if statement? Can my other class access the buttons on the GUI if I make them public, or is there a more efficient way to do this.

```
JPanel foodOptions;
JButton[] button= new JButton[4]; //buttons to send selected object to info panel
static JComboBox[] box= new JComboBox[4];

JPanel search;
JLabel searchL ;
JTextField foodSearch;
JButton startSearch; //button to initialize search for typed food name
JTextArea searchInfo;

JPanel foodProfile;
JLabel foodLabel;
JTextArea foodInfo;
JButton addFood; //but to add food to consumed calories list

JPanel currentStatus;
JLabel foodsEaten;
JComboBox foodsToday;
JLabel calories;
JTextArea totalKCal;
JButton clearInfo; //button to clear food history
```

Comment: I would do this by using the buttons listener and make a new instance of your class with the method, and then just call that method. So for instance `jButton1 actionPerformed { myClass.myMethod(); }` not sure about the syntax but that's basically it

Comment: Take a look at [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and (preferably) [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per people's comments, you need to use listeners of some sort, here is a real basic example to get you started, however I would define your listeners elsewhere in most cases, rather than on the fly:

```
JButton startSearch = new JButton("startSearch");
        JButton addFood = new JButton("addFood");

        startSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //DO SEARCH RELATED THINGS

            }
        });

        addFood.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //DO FOOD ADD RELATED THINGS

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
JButton searchButton = new JButton("Start search");

searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // do some search here
   }
});

JButton addFoodButton= new JButton("Add food");

addFoodButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // add your food
   }
});
```

and so on. If you need to reuse an behaviour through multiple buttons, create a `ActionListener` instance instead of using anonymous classes and assign it multiple times to your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Well there any many ways to do that I guess. I suppose you can do the following:

```
public class Myclass implements ActionListener
{
  private JButton b1,b2;
  private MyClassWithMethods m = new MyClassWithMethods(); 

  // now for example b1
  b1 = new JButton("some action");
  b1.setActionCommand("action1");
  b1.addActionListener(this);

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if ("action1".equals(e.getActionCommand())) 
    {
        m.callMethod1();
    } else {
       // handle other actions here
    }
   }
 }
```

And you can do the same for more buttons and test which action triggered the event and then call the appropriate methods from you class.